# What's the best free way to monitor IIS Logs?

Tags: iis, dashboard, iis-logs

I want to get useful statistics about the website that's hosted on Iis.I want these visualizations through a dashboard.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Tarun, The best way is to use IIS Log monitoring/parser tools. There are plenty to choose from.

Here are a couple I used before, but there are lots of them.

1. [Smarter Stats](https://www.smartertools.com/smarterstats/website-analytics)
2. [Web Trends](https://www.webtrends.com/)

Just search around for IIS Log Parsers and find one you like.